# How to export large amount of objects to separate images in InDesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign, export, automation, illustrator-scripting

I have this photo album with two layers, layouted in InDesign (CS6):

- On the first layer I have all the graphic elements (the gras and the yellow elements)
- On the second layer are portraits (the pixelated profile pictures that you can see below)

I want to print the album with all the graphic elements and print the portraits separately on stickers – just as in the old Panini collection albums.

**My question is: How can I efficiently export all the portraits on layer 2 into separate images?**

Do I have to select all of them individually and export them manually? Or is there a faster way to do so, e.g. with the use of a script?

[image]

Comment: judging by your guides this layout is in InDesign, correct?

Comment: Sorry, sometimes you just forget the obvious. I added a tag, but yes, it's InDesign and I will update the question...

Comment: you have the illustrator scripting tag too that why I wanted to check

Comment: do you have the photos as separate linked files? or are them embedded in the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you'll want to export them as cropped, the one step method would be `File > Export > HTML`.

Set the image resolution at whatever you need for your project, use jpeg export and the highest quality output (all set in the Export dialog). You can toss the HTML file and CSS folder and use just the images.

If your photographs have captions (it looks like they do) and you don't mind rasterizing the text, group each one with its caption, right click *the group* and select "Object Export Options". On the `HTML and ePub` tab, select "Custom Rasterization" and set the resolution and quality as before. Caption and image will now be rasterized as a single image on export.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Darn. This ALMOST fixed my problem.
But, in my case, I wanted to export the images with the **same name as the originals** (we rename with serial numbers for the merchandise images).

They were exported with their original filenames (plus a suffix, but easy to deal with using a batch renamer).
HOWEVER,
The quality is considerably lower than just exporting as JPG, even after exploring the different JPG settings.

Narrowed them down to these "optimal" settings:

- JPG export: **Meduim** quality, **progressive**, **72 dpi**, RGB, anti-alias, embed color profile (sRGB IEC...~) >>resulting file size: **49 Kb**

[image: Export JPEG options]

- HTML export Image: optimised, **Medium**, **progressive**, **96 dpi**, (cropped as layout, etc.) >>resulting file size: **59.6 Kb**, and still looks a lower quality.
- HTML export Image: at **High** quality, **72dpi**, file size is **84.9 Kb**, but has way lower quality vs. JPG export.

[image]

///

**UPDATE!
Found it!**
Here:
[Indesign CS6 Scripting - Exporting images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10983501/indesign-cs6-scripting-exporting-images)

[ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10983501/indesign-cs6-scripting-exporting-images ]

Just needed some tweaking for my own needs. (72dpi, Medium quality, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

There is a perfect script for InDesign to export the cropped pictures from Martin Kraetke ...
https://github.com/le-tex/InDesignScripts/tree/master/image-export