# How to export multiple objects as individual JPGs in InDesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign

I'm hoping the community can help me. I'm having a color disparity issue with the JPGs exported from HTML.

I followed the steps outlined from this thread: [How to export large amount of objects to separate images in InDesign?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/29676/how-to-export-large-amount-of-objects-to-separate-images-in-indesign) to produce an image folder of individual JPGs with their document crops/masks.

The problem is, the color of the JPGs within the images folder are exporting more dull than its original link.

Attached is a screenshot of the document color settings.

[image]

I'm working on Indesign 2021 16.2.1 with macOS Big Sur 11.4.

The HTML exported images are here: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/urjmr4wvg7es8ji/AAAJbFz9iszCpOAOBePtc13_a?dl=0

Some of the original links for what the color should be: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/i1lmrfsqi3wasdq/AAC1xeg2rBjJomLzXlDjT0_Ra?dl=0

I Set the Quality for Individual Images as suggested in this post: https://ajarproductions.com/in5course/?lesson=imagequality

Changing the quality of the individual image to "Use Existing Image for Graphic Object" solved the color disparity problem, but the images did not export with their preferred crops as they appear in the document.

I'm at a loss here. Any help would be so appreciated. Also please let me know if I can provide any additional info.

Comment: The originals are Adobe RGB, the exports show as 'untagged' which will usually be interpreted as sRGB. Assigning Adobe RGB doesn't get back to the original - so something is odd in your export profiling. Exporting an original to sRGB & reopening in Photoshop, I cannot tell the difference, so the original Adobe RGB profile is 'correct' for the original images. I don't have InDesign so I can't check in there.

Comment: hi @Tetsujin thanks for looking into this - agreed it has to be something with the export profiling but I can't seem to pinpoint it. Any recommendations on what to check?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know InDesign at all. Testing in Photoshop I can't reproduce the error… but of course, I can't reproduce your exact method.

Comment: As no-one else has picked up on this, I think you might have to ask Adobe.